# Glimpse 'Routes' and 'Views' tabs are not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, glimpse

I tried glimpse on two different real projects, and for some reason only on one of them glimpse working as intended. On the other one 'Routes' tab does not highlights successfully matched route and 'Views' tab just shows nothing.

I spent some time trying to figure out whats wrong and the only major difference between projects, aside from the version of frameworks (the working one uses MVC4 and the other one MVC5), seems to be that the problematic one uses custom razor view engine and most routes are put into areas. However, search on stackoverflow/google of whether something of it can be the cause gave me nothing.

So, any thoughts on how do I get glimpse to work properly, or at leats where to look?

**UPD**
I checked if custom view engine somehow interfered with  Glimpse work, and indeed, when I commented out following lines, the 'Views' tabs started to work correctly. However, 'Routes' tab still does no show me what routes was executed during requests (only lists them).

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomRazorViewEngine());
```

Here is the code of `CustomRazorViewEngine`:

```
public class CustomRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
    {
        public CustomRazorViewEngine() : base(null)
        {
            AreaViewLocationFormats = new[]
            {
                GetPath("Views/{2}/{1}/{0}.cshtml"),
                GetPath("Views/{2}/{1}/{0}.vbhtml"),
                GetPath("Views/{2}/Shared/{0}.cshtml"),
                GetPath("Views/{2}/Shared/{0}.vbhtml")
            };
            AreaMasterLocationFormats = new[]
            {
                GetPath("Views/{2}/{1}/{0}.cshtml"),
                GetPath("Views/{2}/{1}/{0}.vbhtml"),
                GetPath("Views/{2}/Shared/{0}.cshtml"),
                GetPath("Views/{2}/Shared/{0}.vbhtml")
            };
            AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new[]
            {
                GetPath("Views/{2}/{1}/{0}.cshtml"),
                GetPath("Views/{2}/{1}/{0}.vbhtml"),
                GetPath("Views/{2}/Shared/{0}.cshtml"),
                GetPath("Views/{2}/Shared/{0}.vbhtml")
            };

            ViewLocationFormats = new[]
            {
                GetPath("Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml"),
                GetPath("Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml"),
                GetPath("Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"),
                GetPath("Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml")
            };
            MasterLocationFormats = new[]
            {
                GetPath("Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml"),
                GetPath("Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml"),
                GetPath("Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"),
                GetPath("Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml")
            };
            PartialViewLocationFormats = new[]
            {
                GetPath("Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml"),
                GetPath("Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml"),
                GetPath("Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"),
                GetPath("Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml")
            };

            FileExtensions = new[]
            {
                "cshtml",
                "vbhtml",
            };
        }

        private string GetPath(string fileName)
        {
            var areaName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["areaName"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(areaName))
            {
                return string.Format("~/{0}", fileName);
            }

            return string.Format("~/{0}/{1}", areaName, fileName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the custom view engine do that is different? Just trying to think what the issue might be... Also we should support areas. Are you using attribute routing or something?

Comment: @anthonyv, I have updated post with some info on custom view engine, but I personally still have no idea what here is breaking Glimpse.  
And no, we don't use attribute routing, just RouteConfig with default setup. Also, I wanted to attach some screenshots of glimpse tabs, but apparently I have insufficient SO reputation.